# Tkinter "invalid command name" when closing a window using .after()

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a simple Tkinter program in Spyder that implements a checkbox in the first window and will also check for new data every second using the .after() method to update the interface of the first window.  When exiting that window (clicking the button to destroy it and open the next window), it throws the following errors:

```
invalid command name "1698581045056Check"
    while executing
"1698581045056Check"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "1698581002816Check"
    while executing
"1698581002816Check"
    ("after" script)
```

I've tried putting a try/except block around the .after() command but the library must be handling the exception.  This is the shortened test code that throws the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = None

def Window1():
    global root
    def ChangeWindow():
        root.destroy()
        Window2()
    
    print("Before Root")
    root = tk.Tk()
    print("After Root")
    loop_checkbox = tk.IntVar()
    loop_check_button = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbox', variable=loop_checkbox)
    loop_check_button.pack()
    
    window2_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Go to window 2", command=ChangeWindow)
    window2_button.pack()
    
    Check()
    root.mainloop()
    
def Window2():
    def ChangeWindow():
        window2.destroy()
        Window1()
    
    window2 = tk.Tk()
    window1_button = ttk.Button(window2, text="Go to window 1", command=ChangeWindow)
    window1_button.pack()
    
    window2.mainloop()


def Check():
    global root
    print("Checking")
    #Running code to change the interface from another thread here using queue.get() <-
    root.after(1000, Check)

Window1()
```

Is there something I can add/do to avoid this error?  Thanks.

Comment: You don't have two main loops, and you don't want to instantiate `Tk.tk()` twice.  You should pull the creation of `root` and the call to `root.mainloop()` as the very last line of your file.

Comment: I've run your code a few times and can not generate any error. Does the error occur every time you change windows?

Comment: It does error every time I click the button to change windows from window 1/"root" to window 2.  Maybe it's a Spyder issue?  Also, is there a better way to have multiple windows without instantiating Tk.tk() for each window?

Comment: It maybe a Spyder issue. You might try using `after_cancel` before creating new window.

Comment: the after_cancel() seems to work, thanks!